# How to Open Facebook API to open Login Dialog?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I m using facebook api from https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/ios/ 
and using `[facebook authorize:nil];` to open login dialog. But when I run on simulator it opens facebook dialog for login but when I run it in iphone It opens my facebook Application to login instead of facebook Dialog. I want to show facebook dialog when user is not login otherwise run code that I have applied.

Answer (score 0):

If you logged in the Facebook account once from the simulator it goes to the desired feature next time onwards. Please check it.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook has an Single Sign On technique for permission grant. The tutorial that you are following does the same for you. It will open the Facebook App for you or the Safari, if it is not found. So the authentication process may remain clear under the oAuth protocol.

Comment: What should I have to do in this case I do not want to open facebook app installed on my iphone

Comment: This is the way it works. You can check the SSO to get to know what this is about. You app has no power for authentication, it just gets a message from the other app which if not Facebook app and then it will open the Safari to authenticate the user automatically.